# How to print all genesis accounts and their balances for debugging purpose?

Tags: polkadot, substrate-node-template, runtime

Would it be possible to get the information of all accounts in log? I would need this for debugging purpose.

Can somebody please help me to provide this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for the genesis state this is quite easy. You just need the binary and use the `build-spec` command. Having `jq` ready makes this as easy as:

```bash
polkadot build-spec --dev | jq '.genesis.runtime.balances'
```

Note that on Rococo it is wrapped again in a `runtime_genesis_config`; here you have to use:

```bash
polkadot build-spec --chain rococo-dev | jq '.genesis.runtime.runtime_genesis_config.balances'
```

The output is as expected and shows balances for `//Alice`, `//Bob`, etc.

```
{
  "balances": [
    [
      "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
      1e+18
    ],
    [
      "5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty",
      1e+18
    ],
    …
}
```

Comment: I am getting the output `2023-04-25 18:42:36 Building chain spec `. Am I missing anything?

Comment: That is the first line. You can debug it by removing the `jq` pipe. Otherwise please extend your Q about what binary you are using.

Comment: I got the issue. Thanks. The path is '.genesis.runtime.palletBalances.balances'